# Why the code is sometimes giving me a lower value even tho I wrote "l"?

Tags: python

I wrote a little game to make the computer guess the correct number. However, when I write the letter l, it sometimes gives me a lower value than the previous guess even tho it should constantly be higher (vice versa with h). Do you know why?

```
def computer_guess(x):
    low = 1
    high = x
    feedback = ""
    while feedback != "c":
        if low != high:
            guess = random.randint(low, high)
        else:
            guess = low
        feedback = input(f"Is {guess} too High (H), too Low (L), or correct (C): ".lower())
        if feedback == "h":
            high = guess - 1
        elif feedback == "l":
            low = low + 1

    print(f"Yeyyy, {guess} is the correct answer!!!")

computer_guess(100)
```

Comment: `low = guess + 1`, instead of `low + 1`

Comment: You might also want to consider moving `.lower()` outside of `input()`, i.e., `input(f"...").lower()`

Answer (score 1):

When `feedback == 'l'`, you should code `low = guess + 1`.

> is 4 too high (h), too low (l), or correct (c): l
>
> is 59 too high (h), too low (l), or correct (c): h
>
> is 32 too high (h), too low (l), or correct (c): c
>
> Yeyyy, 32 is the correct answer!!!